# How to differentiate agents that cause harm but may or may not have the intent of doing so?

Tags: adjectives

If I harm someone/something without having the intent to do so, am I being aggressive, hostile, or something else? What if I had the intent?

I'm looking for ways to describe and differentiate agents which cause harm without intent (sometimes without even consciousness, e.g. a disease) from agents that cause harm with intent (e.g. me, hitting someone because I'm angry at them).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

### Background information:

I'm writing an article about the risks of a possible emergence of artificial intelligences with human-level intelligence or beyond. One important part of it is explaining to the author that an AI could cause harm to humans without any intent to do so (much like I do when I accidentally step on ants during a walk in the park). Alternatively, it could also **decide** to harm humans and then act accordingly. I consider both cases fundamentally different, and I refer to them throughout the case, so it would be convenient to have an adjective that summarizes those alignments.

Comment: If you want to get legal and classical, you could refer to [*mens rea*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mens-rea) - The intention or knowledge of wrongdoing that constitutes part of a crime, as opposed to the action or conduct of the accused. Compare with actus reus.

Comment: @JLagana could you provide an example sentence or some addition context. The question is too general as it stands.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, unfortunately. Isn't it possible to perform the same partition using more common words?

Comment: @Phil: Ok, I'll add details

Comment: As Phil Sweet has said, your question is too general.  You could be being "aggressive" or "hostile" to someone/something, and then cause harm to a third party (*i.e.* something/someone other than the person/object you are being aggressive towards.  That would be accidental.

Comment: Anything wrong with **unintentionally harmful** *v.* **intentionally harmful**?

Comment: @TrevorD: Yes, I'm wondering if there's a way to describe this alignments with just one word.

Comment: I can't immediately think of anything, but in an article you could define your own terms at the beginning;  e.g. something  like "Throughout this article, I use *harmful* to mean *unintentionally harmful* and *dangerous* to mean *intentionally harmful*.  (Note that I an **not** suggesting those particular words.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Malevolent** and **negligent** come to mind

> malevolent
>   1:  having, showing, or arising from intense often vicious
>   ill will, spite, or hatred

"Malevolent." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 19 Apr. 2016.

> negligent
>   1 a :  marked by or given to neglect especially habitually or culpably
>   1 b :  failing to exercise the care expected of a reasonably prudent person in like 
>   circumstances

"Negligent." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 19 Apr. 2016.